# Getting Specific Data Through Parent Node

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have XML File which contains different data. In this file under the root node (**PulserDeviceData**), there is one Parent Node (**IdentityNumber**), IdentityNumber contains one child named (Measurement). Measurement contains 4 sub chile **PulserData**. PulserData holds the values for **IdentityNumber**. Pulser data is divided into two groups theoretically i.e., 2 sub children contain the data with the same value of two variables i.e., ( PRF = 1000 & Volt = 50). The next 2 sub children values are coming with (PRF = 5000 & Volt = 50).

Now I want to categorize values on these two variables as fixed values. For example, when values with ( PRF = 1000 & Volt = 50) came I want to populate excel from Row number 50 ..... 100 and when values with setting (PRF = 5000 & Volt = 50) came i want to populate from 101 .... 150

This is how I am reading the data currently

```vb
Set PulsTest = XDoc.SelectNodes("//TestDevice/PulsTestData/PulserDeviceData")
Public sngPulserVolt(0 To 15, 0 To 3) As Single
Public  sngPulserFall(0 To 15, 0 To 3) As Single
Public sngPulserWidth(0 To 15, 0 To 3) As Single

For i = o To Data.Length - 1
     For j = 0 To Data(i).ChildNodes.Length - 1
          If Data(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName = "IdentityNumber" Then
                    intIdentityNumber = Data(i).ChildNodes(j).nodetypedvalue
          End If
     Next
       
     For j = 0 To Data(i).ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes.Length - 1
         sngPulserVolt(intIdentityNumber - 1, j) = CSng(ConDecimalSep(Data(i).ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(0).nodetypedvalue))
         sngPulserFall(intIdentityNumber - 1, j) = CSng(ConDecimalSep(Data(i).ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(1).nodetypedvalue))
         sngPulserWidth(intIdentityNumber - 1, j) = CSng(ConDecimalSep(Data(i).ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(2).nodetypedvalue))
      Next
```

This is How XML look like

```
<PulserDeviceData>
  <IdentityNumber>1</IdentityNumber>
  <Measurements>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-141.25</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>18.77</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>46.13</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>40</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>1000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-162.7</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>23.54</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>74.555</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>60</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>1000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-162.75</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>23.445</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>107.975</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>80</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>5000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-162.75</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>23.395</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>135.275009</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>100</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>5000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
  </Measurements>
</PulserDeviceData>
<PulserDeviceData>
  <IdentityNumber>2</IdentityNumber>
  <Measurements>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-136.85</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>17.66</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>45</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>40</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>1000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-163.65</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>23.745</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>74.55</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>60</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>1000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-163.2</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>23.695</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>107.23</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>80</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>5000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
    <PulserData>
      <PulserAmplitude>-163.45</PulserAmplitude>
      <PulserFall>23.665</PulserFall>
      <PulserWidth>134.715</PulserWidth>
      <SetWidth>100</SetWidth>
      <SetPRF>5000</SetPRF>
      <SetVoltage>50</SetVoltage>
    </PulserData>
  </Measurements>
</PulserDeviceData>
```

I want to make an array for these values (PulserAmplitude, PulserFall, PulserWidth) with two settings of PRF and Voltage. this is how my XML looks like

The identity number will go till 16 I just pasted for 1. So for all identity numbers in my excel sheet first I want to populate the data for PRF = 1000 & Volt = 50 && Next (PRF = 5000 & Volt = 50).

Comment: Is the next identity number and it's measurement data part of a new `<PulserDeviceData>`-Tag or is it part of the same as the first one?

Comment: @FunThomas Yes total number of identity numbers is 16 and all of them will come under PulserDeviceData. and the pattern for all the identification numbers is the same which I pasted there will be 4 Pulser data children. 2 will be with ( PRF = 1000 & Volt = 50) and reaming 2 with  (PRF = 5000 & Volt = 50) .

Comment: So in the XML there is no grouping of a ID and the measurement and you have to rely on the order of the tags (that's not a good design...)

Comment: @FunThomas actually that identity number is acting as an ID number. and Under each identity number that is from 1.... 16 measurement data is coming. the problem is how can I get all values of Pulser data tags for each Identity number (actually ID number) where PRF = 1000 & Volt = 50 and the same goes for another setting of PRF and Volt.

Comment: @FunThomas Data is grouped under Identity number (acts as ID number from 1 -- 16). Under this there is measurement and under measurement there is PulserData. I want to categorize pulser data for each ID i.e., identity number on basic of these two variables PRF and Volt

Comment: a) Without editing a sample output it's very confusing to understand the wanted result. How should this array look like?  b) As you described xml, `IdentityNumber` doesn't represent a *true* parent node, it only precedes a following `Measurement` node block at the same hierarchy level (containing 4 times the `PulserData` set), then you start again with `IdentityNumber` and a following `Measurement`, etc. etc. @EricTuco

Comment: As noted by @FunThomas - you really need to update your sample XML to show at least two representative `Measurement` blocks - as posted it's unclear how the DOM is actually structured when you show only a single `Measurement`.  Ideally update to show an  example which is valid XML (ie. parseable without further edits)

Comment: @TimWilliams I have updated the XML and added the second identity number. the structure is the same till 16 identity numbers.

Comment: OK now it's clearer - `PulserDeviceData` is not the root node as described above: the document "root" is a single element which has all of the content within it - it does not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to point you in the "right" direction, which is to use the XML DOM methods to get at the data in a structured way, rather than looping over child elements of a node.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim doc As Object, nodes As Object, nd As Object, id, measurements As Object, meas As Object
    
    Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    
    doc.LoadXML ReadUTF8("C:\Temp\test.xml")
    
    Set nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//TestDevice/PulsTestData/PulserDeviceData")
    
    For Each nd In nodes
        id = NamedChildValue(nd, "IdentityNumber")
        
        Set measurements = nd.SelectNodes("Measurements/PulserData")
        Debug.Print "----------------------------------"
        Debug.Print "Id=" & id, "#measures=" & measurements.Length
        
        For Each meas In measurements
            Debug.Print "PulserAmplitude", NamedChildValue(meas, "PulserAmplitude")
            Debug.Print "PulserFall", NamedChildValue(meas, "PulserFall")
            Debug.Print "PulserWidth", NamedChildValue(meas, "PulserWidth")
            Debug.Print "SetWidth", NamedChildValue(meas, "SetWidth")
            Debug.Print "SetPRF", NamedChildValue(meas, "SetPRF")
            Debug.Print "SetVoltage", NamedChildValue(meas, "SetVoltage")
        Next meas
    Next nd
End Sub

'helper function
Function NamedChildValue(el, childName As String)
    NamedChildValue = el.SelectSingleNode(childName).nodeTypedValue
End Function

'return text content from a UTF-8 encoded file
Function ReadUTF8(filePath As String) As String
    Dim objStream, strData
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile filePath
        ReadUTF8 = .ReadText()
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```